# Getting the 4 last values from the MySQL table

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

In my MySQL table I have a column called `emails`. How can I get the last 4 values from that column using Doctrine?

Comment: normally the first column in a table is something like ID and is set to be an auto- increment column. With that in place, the query might look somthing like `select * from table order by ID DESC LIMIT 4`

Comment: @DuaneLortie yes, I know how to do it with SQL. I am just wondering how I can do this with Doctrine methods like `getRepository()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write this query in code, if you want to do it with query builder,
you can run this code example:

```
$query = $em->getRepository('TableRepository')
    ->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->orderBy('t.id', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->setMaxResult(4);
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I wanted.